# Android mediaplayer hypothetical: Would it be a good idea to use the java timer to schedule MediaPlayer events?

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Just a quick hypothetical question to solve a problem I am having. I am making extensive use of the `MediaPlayer` class in my app, and my app seems to act strangely when I press buttons (linked to the `MediaPlayer` ) very quickly. Would scheduling `prepare()`, `start()` and `reset()` be a good way to prevent issues?

Comment: The MediaPlayer has a fixed set of states -- if you call something out of order, you're going to get bad behavior. I'm guessing a Timer wouldn't help

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Well, the straight up order isn't my problem. I think the problems arise because the methods I put the `prepare()`, `start()` and `reset()` in end up overlapping when they are called (in good order) on their own.